# How to do whole function not just half?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, microsoft-metro, async-await

i'm currently coding C# app for Windows Store.

I have Cache class, News UserControl class and MainPage class

I'm calling in MainPage constructor Cache class and then call InitializeData for News class where i using data from Cache, but there is problem, in Cache constructor i receiving datas but he didnt do whole function, he switching from Cache constructor to InitializeData at third await function.

MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Cache.Cache cache = new Cache.Cache();
    NewsContent.InitializeData(cache.MyData);
}
```

Cache:

```
    public Cache()
    {
        Initialization = Init();
    }

    public Task Initialization
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private async Task Init()
    {
        try
        {
            cS        = await folder.CreateFileAsync("cache.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            cS_titles = await folder.CreateFileAsync("titles_cache.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            string contentOfFile = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(cS);
            int contentLength = contentOfFile.Length;

            if (contentLength == 0) // download data for first using
            {
                await debug.Write("Is empty!");

                //.......
                // ....

                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(cS, file_content);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(cS_titles, file_content_titles);
            }
            else // check for same data, if isnt same download new, else nothing
            {
                await debug.Write(String.Format("Isnt empty. Is long: {0}", contentLength)); // here he break and continue to NewsContent.InitializeData(cache.MyData);

                // ....
                // ....
            }

            await MyFunction(); // i need get constructor to this point then he will do NewsContent.InitializeData(cache.MyData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Is this possible to do it? For any idea thank you!

Comment: It seems whoever designed the `Cache` class understood how is async initialization supposed to work. Do you? If not, read [Stephen Cleary's article about `async` and constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: Then why do you have the `Initialization` property that isn't actually used?

Comment: But its used in Constructor with function Init, i programming for metro about 3 days, it's complete diffrent from basic C#.

Comment: Yeah, you set the property, but then never use its value. That means you might as well remove it completely.

Comment: Ok, so how to use it in MainPage constructor? Because its async it will need some-how code it and that's what i dont know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28572/discussion-between-user1085907-and-svick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stephen Cleary's article on `async` and constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) describes how to make this work.

In your case, I think the factory pattern (as suggested in Jon's answer) won't work for `MainPage`, because it's a GUI component. But the second approach, The Asynchronous Initialization Pattern, will work.

You already implemented that pattern for `Cache`, now you also need to implement it for `MainPage`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    Initialization = InitializeAsync();
}

public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    Cache.Cache cache = new Cache.Cache();
    await cache.Initialization;
    NewsContent.InitializeData(cache.MyData);        
}
```

If `MainPage` has some events that depend on the initialization being complete, you can make then `async` and add `await this.Initialization` at their beginning. Also, you might want to enable buttons or things like that at the end of `MainPage`'s `InitializeAsync()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you call an async method and never wait for it to finish, basically.

The whole point of an async method is that you *don't* block... and your constructor can't be asynchronous itself.

One option would be to write an asynchronous static method to create a cache:

```
static async Task<Cache> CreateCache()
{
    // Change your InitializeData to return the data which the cache needs
    var data = await InitializeData();
    return new Cache(data);
}
```

Fundamentally you still need whatever calls CreateCache to understand that it's happening asynchronously though. You don't want to block the UI thread waiting for it all to initialize.

EDIT: I hadn't spotted that this is called from the `MainPage` constructor. You could potentially apply the same approach again:

```
public static async Task<MainPage> CreateMainPage()
{
    var cache = await Cache.CreateCache();
    return new MainPage(cache);
}
```

This is assuming you really, really can't let the main page be created without the cache being completely initialized. If you *could* handle that (e.g. showing something like a "Loading..." status until it's finished initializing) then that would be better.

Comment: How would you call that when creating `MainPage`?

Comment: So i should call CreateMainPage in constructor of MainPage? And move all from Cache constructor to function CreateCache?

Comment: @user1085907: No, CreateMainPage calls the MainPage constructor. You can't write asynchronous constructors, and you need to start thinking more asynchronously.